# Concatenating to a file name before the ‘.’ Filename extension in Java

Tags: java

I can’t seem to find a way of concatenating to a file name before the “.” extension in Java and I’m not entirely sure how I would go about this.

I have already tried:

```
String s = r + "V1";
```

Where the variable `r` contains the value of `myFile.txt` and the output is: `myFile.txtV1`, but what I need to achieve is `myFileV1.txt` as I don’t want to overwrite the existing file with the same name but concatenate the `V1` before the `.` filename extension when the file is written.

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In case file name can contain more then one dot like `foo.bar.txt` you should find index of last dot ([`String#lastIndexOf(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int)) can be useful here).

- To get file name without extension (`foo.bar` part) [substring(int, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)) full file name from index 0 till index of that last dot.
- To get extension (`.txt` part from last dot till the end of string) [substring(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) from last dot index.

So your code can look like:

```
int lastDotIndex = r.lastIndexOf('.');
String s = r.substring(0, lastDotIndex ) + "V1" + r.substring(lastDotIndex);
```

Comment: Thanks. Although it will throw a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the filename contains no dot at all. It should rather be like: `String s = (lastDotIndex > -1) ? ... : r + "V1"`.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi)'s [FilenameUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html) class to get the file's base name and extension.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

...

File file = ...
String filename = file.getName();
String base = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(filename);
String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(filename);
String result = base + "-something-here" + "." + extension;
```

Comment: Only gotcha here is if you filename is missing extension, then you are adding a trailing dot "." which is most probably not desired.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [String.indexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and [String.substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) to split the string up and rebuild your updated version.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (assuming that you have only one `'.'` in the name of your file):

```
String[] x = r.split("\\.");
String s = x[0]+"V1."+x[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Another [apache commons](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.5) method based on [StringUtils.substringBeforeLast()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringBeforeLast-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) and [StringUtils.substringAfterLast](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringAfterLast-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

```java
String newPath = StringUtils.substringBeforeLast(filePath, ".") +
    "_updated." + StringUtils.substringAfterLast(filePath, ".");
```

<sub>NB: You still need to check if the file actually contains the dot character or otherwise the result won't be consistent.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = r.substring(0,r.indexOf(".")) + "V1" + r.substring(a.indexOf("."));
```

Reminder that extensions are technically platform specific.  Also, you probably want to have separate variables for the name and extension and combine them together at the end.  Last caveat is that this code will not work if there are multiple period symbols in the filename (e.g. hello.world.txt)